# RSS Feed videos for spotify

Tags: rss, spotify, feed

I want to know if it is possibile to delivery videos on Spotify using the RSS Feed?

I tried to put this configuration `<enclosure url="https://xxx.mp4" length="xxx" type="video/mp4"/>` inside my RSS Feed but when I link the rss feed to Spotify, I have the following error:

> We’re unable to accept podcasts with videos.

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot.